# Is it possible to use gt functions with a gtsummary table (or convert a gt object to a gtsummary object)?

Tags: ms-word, type-conversion, gtsummary, gt

Here is my situation:

1. I use `gtsummary` to create at `tbl_summary` class variable
2. I need to do some formatting that is not possible with `gtsummary` - but instead requires `gt` functions
3. Therefore, I convert my `tbl_summary` to a `gt_tbl` using `as_gt()`
4. The problem is that now can no longer export to MS Word, nor can I convert back to `tbl_summary`

Since `gtsummary` is a wrapper around `gt` it seems like there should be a way to either:

1. Use `gt` functions directly on the `gtsummary` object without converting it, or
2. Convert the `gt` object back to a `gtsummary` object

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options for you:

1. Instead of Word output, use RTF. RTF is supported by Word and the {gt} package.
2. If you need to stick with Word output, you'll need to use {flextable} to perform the additional formatting, e.g. `tbl_summary(...) %>% as_flex_table() %>% <flextable formatting functions>`

Comment: I really love the package and appreciate you taking the time to answer. 

I have tried both of your suggestions before coming here. Unfortunately, the formatting that I need gt for disappears and I need to do it manually in word, which defeats the whole purpose. 

Please consider adding this functionality, as it would be quite useful, and I know others who have run into the same roadblock.

Comment: What formatting are you doing with gt that is unavailable in flextable?

Comment: Having the same or similar issues. Seems like the best solution would be an update to gt::gtsave() write to .docx format and preserve formatting.  RTF just doesn't cut it.

Comment: It's on the {gt} roadmap to support Word output. FYI

Comment: FYI @MikeS, a gtsummary table supports very minimal formatting, and exports table to gt, flextable, huxtable, kableExtra, kable, and tibble formats. The gt and flextable pkgs have 100+ functions to style a table. There is no way to support conversion of a gt object to gtsummary while maintaining all styling.

Comment: @Daniel D. Sjoberg...I appreciate the insights. I had heard gt --> word was on the horizon - but I'm not holding my breath. For the time being, I'll just mange with my workarounds. Thanks again for the great package (gtsummary)!